# Adding a second column as a function of first with data.table's (`:=`)

Tags: r, data.table

I'm relatively new to data.table, been using dplyr before.

When trying to create multiple new columns, where the second is a function of the first, I always get an error **"object column.1 cannot be found"**.

This behaviour is possible in dplyr with the `mutate()` and pipe operator (`%>%`). Did I miss something or can this behaviour not be replicated with data.table's `:=` ?

```
 x[, `:=`(column.1 = a / b,
          column.2 = column.1 / 2)] # not possible?
```

Comment: `(column.1 = column.1 <- a / b, column.2 = column.1 / 2)` should work

Comment: I think you should be able to do it... `x[, col1 := a / b][, col2 := col1 / 2]`